# npm package for merging html files

Tags: html, node.js, npm

I've a requirement where in I need to merge multiple HTML files into one. I need to remove the HTML tags and the HEAD tag and merge the two HTML files to have one HTML tag and HEAD tag. Are there any nodejs packages which already do this. Because I do not want to reinvent the wheels.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at gulp. They have minification for html which is realy good. They might have some merge tool aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably there is no ready solution for your exact use case but you may be able to write something quickly using some of the available HTML parsers for Node:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse5
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2

or even a DOM implementation:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom